# Merging Overlapping Columns in data.frame

Tags: r, merge, overlap

I have a newly created `data.frame` that is the result of joining two other frames by a common key, but they overlap exactly where there is missing data.

How would I go about successfully merging them together?

Reprex

```
df <- data.frame(Index = c(1:5), Label.x = c("A", NA, NA, "D", "E"), Label.y = c(NA, "B", "C", NA, NA))
df
    Index Label.x Label.y
    1       A    <NA>
    2    <NA>       B
    3    <NA>       C
    4       D    <NA>
    5       E    <NA>
```

Desired Result

```
Index Label
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     D
5     E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df <-
  data.frame(
    Index = c(1:5),
    Label.x = c("A", NA, NA, "D", "E"),
    Label.y = c(NA, "B", "C", NA, NA)
  )

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  transmute(Label = coalesce(Label.x, Label.y))
#>   Label
#> 1     A
#> 2     B
#> 3     C
#> 4     D
#> 5     E
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Label = coalesce(Label.x,Label.y)) %>%
  select(Index, Label)
```

Output:

```
  Index Label
1     1     A
2     2     B
3     3     C
4     4     D
5     5     E
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that only works if you have precisely 1 missing value per row, as in your example:

```
df$Label <- ifelse(is.na(df$Label.x),df$Label.y,df$Label.x)
df <- df[,c("Index","Label")]
```

First you should check that it is the case by doing something like this and seeing if the answer is true:

```
all(apply(df,1,function(x) sum(is.na(x))==1))
```

Hope this is close to what you are looking for.